# Lcov report from Karma is not getting uploaded into sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, karma-coverage

I am trying to publish lcov reports from karma to sonar, the report is getting generated in jenkins but its not getting uploaded into sonar. Our's is a angularJS maven project. Already sonar is analysing junit testing now I'm trying to analysize javascript using karma but ist not happening. I tried adding

Kindly let me know if I am missing something....

```
#Karma reports

sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath=reports/

sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=src/main/webapp/coverage/lcov.info
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read How to Ask.

Comment: Did you check the logs of the analysis? You should provide them if you want some help. You should also provide the versions of SonarQube and of the JavaScript plugin you're using.