# Publishing Karma result in sonar

Tags: sonarqube, lcov, karma-coverage

I'm trying to publish karma report in sonar.Ours is a angularJS application Maven project.Already sonarqube is displaying junit code coverage.I have generated lcov.info file but sonarqube is not picking up the file.I have included following properties in sonar but its not working

sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath=reports/

sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=src/main/webapp/coverage/lcov.info

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question looks a lot like [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536825/lcov-report-from-karma-is-not-getting-uploaded-into-sonar) on which the poster did not answer comments.

Comment: Please specify version, provide logs explain what you have tried. Question cannot be answered if you don't provide details about what you are actually doing and what is not working.